# Check which display an application is using

Tags: process, display, x-server

The machine I'm working from has many active X displays (one standard X server and many VNC displays). It is also running a handful of GUI applications, which appear on an X display.

Assuming I have the PID (using `ps`) is there a method to determine which X screen the process is using, or even the value the `DISPLAY` variable held when launched?

Even better if there's a method to show the value of `DISPLAY` for the process and all of its children process, in case some processes spawn their GUI as a child process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `root` access (or `sudo ps`) then you can display the environment of a process with the `e` option.  Inside here you should be able to see the `DISPLAY` variable (if it's set).  You probably need `ww` to ensure the output doesn't get truncated.

e.g.

```
% ps wwep $$ | tr ' ' '\012' | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=:0
```

So my current shell is talking to `:0`.

Many OS's protect the environment from other users (because it may leak sensitive information), so a normal user can only see their own process environments.  `root` can see every user's.

Comment: I do have access to sudo/root so this works great, thanks.